# how can you make an executable file of a jakarta EE project in intellij

Tags: java, build

i finished the coding of a dynamic web project with Java in IntelliJ and now I want to build an executable jar file so I don’t have to use an editor like IntelliJ to run it.  Is there a way to do it? It runs on an local Apache TomCat.

Comment: What did you do, exactly, that "didn't work?"  We'll need more info about what frameworks and libraries you used in your application, so we can advise you how to set up a real (without IntelliJ) environment.

Comment: The usual answer is to build a **war** file. Try `mvn package`

Comment: Also a war file needs an execution environment. Building into a jar means (to me) the container should be bundled as well - something that is not achieved by just running mvn package.

Comment: I tried Build --> Build Artifacts --> Java_Dynamic_Web_Project:war exploded --> Build

Answer (score 0):

With the term "Apache Server" many people refer to [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/).
This one does not serve Java Web applications, therefore I assume you are referring to [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/).

Your web application requires a runtime environment, which is not only the Java but also a servlet container. Apache Tomcat is one possible choice here.

So bundling both (the servlet container and your application) into one executable jar is possible. The [Jenkins project](https://www.jenkins.io/) has done so with their installation - just check out their [download for the generic package (war)](https://www.jenkins.io/download/). You can drop it into an existing container like Apache Tomcat or run it directly like an executable jar.

The keyword you are searching for is `embedded Tomcat`. Googling for that produces results like

- https://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-embed-tomcat-server-into-java-web-applications
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat
- http://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/tomcat/embedding-tomcat

Be aware that Tomcat is not the only servlet engine that can be embedded, and adding another framework like [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) can make your life easier. It depends on what else you intend to do.

Comment: ok thx I will try this out. Yes Apache Tomcat was what I was referring to. The point of this is to set up a simple application with 2 servlets as an university project.